# How to close an open collapsed navbar when clicking outside of the navbar element or clicking on a link in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

in bootstap 3 is like this =>

```
$(document).on('click.nav','.navbar-collapse.in',function(e) {
    if( $(e.target).is('a') ) {
        $(this).removeClass('in').addClass('collapse');
    }
});
```

how to do this in bootstrap 4 alpha 5.thanks here's the codepen of navbar 4:
http://codepen.io/parlop/pen/BQoNNx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think mostly what you need to do it change the class names, for instance in the code i can't see a class named "navbar-collapse":

```
$(document).on('click',function(e) {
    if(  $(e.target).attr('class') != 'navbar' ) {
        $('#navbarResponsive').removeClass('in');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me on Bootstrap 4

```
    $('body').on('click', function(e) {
        if($(e.target).closest('.navbar').length === 0) {
            // click happened outside of .navbar, so hide
            var opened = $('.navbar-collapse').hasClass('collapse');
            if ( opened === true ) {
                $('.navbar-collapse').collapse('hide');
            }
        }
    });
```